# javascript programatically equal to esc key

Tags: javascript, jquery, key

I've learned that the programmatically javascript use of esc key is no more working on chrome and other browsers. **Is there an alternative equal function which is working?**

I have an input field which is traced by some jQuery scripts. If I load the site, always the multiple autocomplete pop up appears as open.

*[Demo JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/doschni/2fuX5/)*

Without the following snippet, the problem is gone, but then the clear-icon don't appears by prefilled input value.

**JS**

```
$('.clearable').trigger('input');
```

Until now I just can press esc on my keyboard or click with the mouse anywhere. Is there an automatically solution?

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery's API documentation is pretty helpful, I ran into a different problem earlier this month, different from yours and I learnt it from jquery.com , well as I have used autocomplete, here is the easier version that you can check to work with,
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
It helped me, I added features afterwards. :) btw, I did not totally  understand your question, if you define a little bit more of your problems, people would find more tags in their heads to help you out with. 
Thanks,
Shayan-Ahmad.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Shayan, that was the right input! I'd search for autocomplete examples and found the perfect fitting one. It's unbelievable, this autocomplete-code can be extremely customized. Now my solution as follows:

```
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "Scheme"
];

$(function() {
  $('#tags').autocomplete({
     source : availableTags, minLength : 0
  });
  $('#tags').focus(function() {
     $('#tags').autocomplete("search", "");
  });
});
```